# How to control the href attribute in thymeleaf

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new for thymeleaf.

The question is easy when it's in jsp. But it beats me in thymeleaf.

I want to complete this function as below:

```
if (page.number<=1)
 html like this:
  <li class="q-pagination-disabled">Pre</li>
else
 <li><a href="/pages/{page.number-1}">Pre</a></li>
```

But I can't finish it with th:if,th:href,th:remove and so on.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following and let me know if it worked for you

```
<li th:if="${page.number le 1}" class="q-pagination-disabled">Pre</li>
<li th:if="${page.number gt 1}"><a th:href="@{/pages/{page}(page=${page.number-1})}">Pre</a></li>
```